# (rails) Order by Number of Likes on a Website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, models

I have a model called websites that `has_many :likes`, and of course another model called likes with `belongs_to :website`. I want to get an array of all the websites but order them by the number of likes a website has.

helpful info:

I have it set up so `@website.likes` will return the likes from `@website`. (`@website.likes.count` is the number of likes a website has)

> I want to get an array of all the websites but order them by the number of likes a website has.

Comment: `sort` doesn't do it by SQL IIRC

Comment: This might be acceptable if the number of sites in @popularwebsites is low. But if you pull all websites into that array first and then do the sort on the fly, it will become expensive and fast. Also, this suffers from something called N+1 query problem as x.likes.count has to make a database query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have posted, you can do a join onto `likes` and then order by the count. Performance may be a bit iffy depending on indexing etc. You'll have slightly different syntax depending on if you're running Rails 2 or 3.

An alternative would be to maintain a denormalised `likes_count` column on `websites` which is updated when a `Like` model object is saved.

Then you just need to query on `Website` and specify an order `likes_count` descending (and is easily indexed).

To do this, create a `likes_count` integer column on the `websites` and specify the `:counter_cache` option on the `belongs_to` declaration in the `Likes` model. e.g:

```
class Likes
  belongs_to :website, :counter_cache => true
end
```

Check out http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html for more info

Comment: Fast and simple! Thanks! (I take it everyone else response worked too!)

Comment: Cool solution! Downside to this is that, say, should you remove a like from the db console, then the removal wouldn't be reflected on the likes_count. Not a bid deal in this case, but something to be aware of.

Comment: @randomguy is correct. This denormalisation technique relies on creating/destroying `Like` objects to be done via Ruby, and letting the callbacks in `ActiveRecord` take care of the housekeeping. If you do it outside of your app code, then you need to do that housekeeping yourself, or your denormalised data gets into an invalid state.

Answer (score 2):

This query should give you what you need:

```
all(:select => 'websites.*, count(*) as count',
  :joins => :likes,
  :group => :websites,
  :order => 'count DESC')
```

Comment: it won't return websites without any likes because the inner joins removes all website which have no likes from the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT Websites.*, COUNT(Like.ID) AS Liked
FROM websites
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Like ON websites.ID = Like.website_id
GROUP BY Like.website_id ORDER BY Liked DESC
```